# in_array возвращает true для отсутствующего ключа

Tags: php

Почему на выходе `true`, ведь строки `"test"` нет в ключах массива?

```
echo in_array("test", array_keys(array(1))) ? true : false; //true
```

Comment: А в чем смысл `? true : false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разве в таком случае "test" не приводится к инт? У вас массив ключей от этого массива будет `array(1) { [0]=> int(0) }` И переменная тест приведенная к инт также будет ноль, вот оно и находит. 
Используйте `echo in_array("test", array_keys(array(1)), true) ? true : false;`

Comment: А еще лучше `echo in_array("test", array_keys(array(1)), true)`. Ведь in_array как раз и возвращает true если элемент найден, иначе false.

Answer (score 0):

В функции `in_array` есть третий параметр `strict` - если установлен в `TRUE` тогда функция `in_array()` также проверит соответствие типов параметра `needle` и соответствующего значения массива `haystack`.

```
var_dump( in_array("test", array_keys(array(1)), true));
```